What files would be good to copy from main drive to backup drive
What files would be good to copy from the main drive to backup drive?
I have a script that compresses and sends files such as document,pictures,etc.
I have heard about copy /home/me/.
Would that be useful if my O.S. needed to be re-installed?

Usual rule: "If it’s Not in Three Places it Doesn’t Exist". And that means three different media.

I do not backup system. But do backup /home, my data partition(s) which are not in /home, and export a list of installed apps into /home so backed up. If you have server apps like database or web then you need those that are in / (root). You may need some in /etc if you edit system files. I edit grub, but just copy that into /home so backed up. Some discussion of what & how to backup. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2456011

It's really a matter of preference. If you don't mind or maybe even prefer reinstalling the OS instead of copying from a full backup / clone, then you may backup only /home (and maybe /root), /etc and bits in /var (like /var/lib). Or in other words, in "unified-bin" systems, what you probably want to skip is /usr (and /opt, if exists).

This is veering towards opinion, so I'm going to generalise in an attempt to make it useful for future readers too.

What files would be good to copy from the main drive to backup drive?

This depends entirely on what you want to achieve with your backup drive. As a starting point you should copy everything. Then decide what you can afford to lose.
One possible split might be this, so that you could backup home directories more frequently that the OS itself

Everything except the contents of the pseudo-directories (/proc, /sys) and transients (/dev, /run, /tmp, /var/tmp) and home directories (/home)
Home directories (/home)

In terms of backups, I use rsnapshot layered on top of rsync, but there are quite a number of different options out there. (I also use the commercial Linux Free Agent from Veeam, but that may not be for everyone.) Beware that if you use timeshift you need to read the documentation carefully to make sure you completely understand what it is - and is not - backing up for you.
